# Select all tables with same columns by suffix and merging them into new one

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I have an arbitrary set of tables with exactly the same structure (columns) and all of the tables have the same suffix `_data`.

What I've tried:

`CREATE TABLE`global_data`AS SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM`v_data`UNION ALL SELECT * FROM`x_data`UNION ALL SELECT * FROM`z_data`UNION ALL SELECT * FROM`d_data`) X GROUP BY ('id') ORDER BY 1`

But as a result i'me getting only one single row even without auto increment colimn, but I need all the rows that exists in each of the table snd with autoincrement column.

So what I need is an SQL query for:

1. Select all tables by suffix.
2. Create a new one table with merged table values, where duplicates
   should be skipped, and the remaining unique values needs to by merged into a
   new one.
3. In result table should be `id` column with Unique and AutoIncrement attributes.

Comment: Need more info on how data result should be. currently for suffix you can use columnname " like '%_data'  "

Answer (score 0):

This answer uses a prepared statement, lots of people here will give you loads of grief about it, so make sure you are aware of the risks of SQL injection..

```
-- Create some tables, drop them if they exist already.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table1_Data;

CREATE TABLE Table1_Data
(
Id INTEGER,
StoredValued VARCHAR(10)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table2_Data;

CREATE TABLE Table2_Data
(
Id INTEGER,
StoredValued VARCHAR(10)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table3_Data;

CREATE TABLE Table3_Data
(
Id INTEGER,
StoredValued VARCHAR(10)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Table4_Data;

CREATE TABLE Table4_Data
(
Id INTEGER,
StoredValued VARCHAR(10)
);

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Result;

CREATE TABLE Result
(
Id INTEGER,
StoredValued VARCHAR(10)
);

-- Insert some data into the tables
INSERT INTO Table1_Data VALUES (1,'Test'),(2,'Testy'),(3,'Testing');
INSERT INTO Table2_Data VALUES (1,'Foo'),(2,'Fooby'),(3,'Foober');
INSERT INTO Table3_Data VALUES (1,'Bar'),(2,'oobar'),(3,'Barbo');
INSERT INTO Table4_Data VALUES (1,'Bar'),(2,'Testy'),(3,'JubJub');

-- Create a statement to execute
SELECT CONCAT('INSERT INTO Result',GROUP_CONCAT(' SELECT * FROM ',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME SEPARATOR ' UNION ')) INTO @query
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE '%_Data';

-- Execute the statement
PREPARE stmt1 FROM @query; 
EXECUTE stmt1; 
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1; 

-- Get the results from our new table.
SELECT *
FROM Result;
```